# WPF pages with navigation on page using MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I currently try to look deeper in the MVVM mechanic and commands and I try to figure out, how to use a pages application without a navigation bar, but with navigation buttons on each page.

I found [THIS](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/) example, but the problem here is, that the navigation is built inside an extra content control. This is fine if you want to have a extra navigation bar, but if your application should look a little more like a wizard application (see picture beneath), then you need to have the navigation anchored on each page, such as a back button on the bottom left and a forward button to the next page on the bottom right.

[image: Wizard Application]

The point is, I do not understand how I can connect a ICommand to a specific button on a page, that tells the mainframe, which page should be loaded on click.

How can I archive this mechanic while using MVVM patterns?
What do I have to change on the program (see the link above) to make this happen?

Thank you very much.
Best regards,
SKiD.

**EDIT1:**

Okay, let me show you a concrete example just with two pages. I have the MainWindow:

**MainWindow XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="mainFrame" Margin="5" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is nothing else, just the mainFrame which loads the first page in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mainFrame.Navigate(new Page1());
    }
```

I have further the two pages which have almost the same structure (for this example) but will be different in the real application. I have to mention here, that the navigation is on the pages and not as an extra frame inside of the MainWindow:

**Page01**:

```
<Page x:Class="TestWPF.Page1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
    Title="Page1">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Page 01" Grid.Row="0" />

        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="ToPage02" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Page02**:

```
<Page x:Class="TestWPF.Page2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
    Title="Page2">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Page 02" Grid.Row="0" />

        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="ToPage01" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

As you can see, the Buttons for going back to the last page are on the pages. Only the first page will be created on the main page and loaded. Now the question, if you imagine that there is an MVVM construct behind (such as a ViewModel and a Model for each side), how does this fit there, if I should use commands for calling the next page like mentioned in the linked tutorial above?

Comment: Could you please make your question more specific? As it stands it is hard for us to answer.

Comment: Fakrudeen I have updated my first post. I added some code and maybe it is now a little bit more understandable what I was trying to say.